# Rails split URL into different parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I split this URL format into 3 chunks as shown in image?

[image]

I need to be able to access all 3 elements separately.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a route in this format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're talking about split the string into these parts, you can obtain it like this:

```
string = "https://ucarecdn.com/8a673d45-4345-4089-a7ae-d28bf112c407~12/"
first_chunk = string.split("/")[2]
second_chunk = strint.split("/")[3].split("~")[0]
third_chunk = strint.split("/")[3].split("~")[1]
```

Comment: glad to help! =)

Answer (score 5):

For future readers: The ruby way to do this is with URI.parse

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html)

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
uri.scheme
#=> "http"
uri.host
#=> "foo.com"
uri.path
#=> "/posts"
uri.query
#=> "id=30&limit=5"
uri.fragment
#=> "time=1305298413"

uri.to_s
#=> "http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
```

Comment: the same docs also describe the `split` method, which can give you the decomposition of the URI all at once.
`["http", nil, "foo.com", nil, nil, "/posts", nil, "id=30&limit=5", "time=1305298413"]` which are given in the following order:  scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment